# Rails (generate model) is creating a singularized table instead of plural -- the model is also looking for a singular table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I used the command:

`$ rails g model Equipment`

and rails performed the following:

```
  invoke  active_record
  create    db/migrate/20160822040448_create_equipment.rb
  create    app/models/equipment.rb
  invoke    test_unit
  create      test/models/equipment_test.rb
  create      test/fixtures/equipment.yml
```

As you can see, the migration is singular! So I renamed the migration file and the table name as follows:

```
class CreateEquipments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :equipments do |t|
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

---

Now, after running `$ rake db:migrate` starting Rail's console `$ rails c`, it errors out saying it cannot find the table when I try to initiate an Equipment:

```
>> Equipment.new
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "equipment" does not exist
LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"equipment"'::regclass
                                          ^
:               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                     pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
                FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                  ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
               WHERE a.attrelid = '"equipment"'::regclass
                 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
               ORDER BY a.attnum

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "equipment" does not exist
LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"equipment"'::regclass
                                          ^
:               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                     pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
                FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                  ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
               WHERE a.attrelid = '"equipment"'::regclass
                 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
               ORDER BY a.attnum
```

---

I was able to patch it up by adding the following line to the model:

```
    class Equipment < ActiveRecord::Base
        self.table_name = 'equipments'
        # ...
    end
```

but, although that fixes the issue, I want to know what's causing the problem to begin with.

Final Note: I tried running #pluralize method on the console, and it wouldn't pluralize the string 'Equipment' in there either:

```
>> 'Equipment'.pluralize
=> "Equipment"
>> 'door'.pluralize
=> "doors"
```

Comment: In English some words either don't have a plural, only have a plural or both plural and singular are the same. In this case there is no such word 'equipments' and we use modifiers to specify singular vs plural. That piece of equipment. That pile of equipment.

Answer (score 8):

Equipment does not have a plural

http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/equipments-equipment-noncount-mass-noun-singular-plural

This is expected behaviour for such words.

Comment: I will blame this on English not being my first language, but I do feel somewhat dumb

Comment: @DiegoDiazdeBerenguer don't worry that's what I feel frequently being a developer

Answer (score 0):

This issue may have arisen because of a manual configuration setting for this particular word, causing Rails to recognize it as both singular and plural. It is advisable to verify and rectify this in the following file:

config/initializers/inflections.rb